# Distinguish a simply connected figures?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, blob

So I have a binary matrix in Matlab. 
It is basically a blob (pixels of value 1) surrounded by a neutral background (value 0).

I want to figure out whether this blob is simply connected or not. 
Figure below is a straightforward example.

[image: Connectedness]

How can this be achieved?
Notably I understand that every path in a pixelated image can be created by choosing from 4 adjacent elements (up, down, left, right) or 8 adjacent elements etc - it doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
%// Assuming bw1 is the input binary matrix

[L,num] = bwlabel( ~bw1 );
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,L(:),1:num));
[~,ind] = max(counts);
bw2 = ~(L==ind);

%// Output decision
[L,num] = bwlabel( bw1 );
if ~nnz(bw1~=bw2) && num==1
    disp('Yes it is a simply connected blob.')
else
    disp('Nope, not a simply connected blob.')
end
```

Comment: Undoubtedly the code is short and appears to work like a charm. I am ready to accept your answer but could you please give a little comment regarding the reasoning behind *counts* and *ind* ?

Comment: @Pranasas Main Point: Those first four un-commented lines of codes basically give filled blobs. 
1. `counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,L(:),1:num));` gives you count of pixels of each blob in the inverted image.
2. Find the biggest blob from them, which is done by `[~,ind] = max(counts);` and `L==ind`.
3. Invert the biggest blob which would give filled blobs in the original matrix.

Decision part: Compare filled blob with the original one and thus help us with deciding if it is simply connected or not. Hope this makes sense.